# searching query to mysql in angularjs using ng-keyup but $http only after 3 seconds

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, keyup

I want to make online search in angularjs, using ng-keyup function. But I suppose that it is wrong to make query to BD on each keyup. So how can I set timer that will make $http service work only if in last 3 second there were no keyups?

```
<input type="text" ng-keyup="search(param.values, param.url)">
```

JS:

```
app.controller('searchCtrl', function($scope,$rootScope,$http){
$scope.search = function( values , type) {
    var data={};
    data.values=values;
    data.type=type;
    console.log(data);
    $http.post("search.php", data).then(function success (response) {
            console.log(response.data);
            $rootScope.search_result=response.data;
        },function error (response){
            console.log(response.data);
        }
    );
};
});
```

Comment: use bedounce. https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `ng-model-options` to `debounce` your input value which will tell angular to update ng-model to update after a particular amount of time. Then switch to `ng-change` event would make more sense instead of `ng-keyup`. In short, we use `debounce` to delay our API call.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="value" ng-change="search(param.values, param.url)" 
  ng-model-options="{ debounce: 3000 }"
```

Comment: So with ng-change and ng-model-options value will be changed only if last keyup was 3 seconds ago, right?

Comment: Yupe.. debounce will wait until 3 seconds when user stop typing... we used `ng-change` because we want to keep track of model value of input field..

Comment: @RoGGeR Glad to know that it helped, Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Waiting for a few seconds in a search module is not very ergonomic / user friendly.

What we usually do is cancel the previous request each time a new character is entered by the user.

You can do this by passing a promise to the `timeout` property of you [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) request.

```
$http.get(request, {timeout: promise}).then...
```

You initialise the promise at the start of your search function:

```
abort = $q.defer();
```

This way, each time the function is called, you can check if there's a promise and resolve it (cancel it) before making a new request.

```
if(abort) {
  abort.resolve();
}
```

Check out the [working plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/1dLsBFpY6Uqh60EfP51a?p=preview). (and open the console to see requests being cancelled as you type.)

Comment: Can you write more detailed plz?) I'm not strong in angularjs at all. What for $q service in working plunker?

Comment: @RoGGeR for promises I can only redirect you to https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q It's too vas a subject to explain here.

Comment: I thought $q is your own service. Link is more than enough, thanks! :)